# User DisplayName on first-time login

Tags: user-profile, user-information-list, profile-sync

Folks, we've got the problem. We are using Claims auth on a SharePoint farm.

As usual (windows auth) when user login at first-time to SharePoint site, he sees his DisplayName in welcomecontrol.ascx (rigth-bottom part of page). In this case DisplayName resolved from ActiveDirectory (i'm not sure, but it's looks like that).

But we want the same behaviour with Claims auth. All of our users sees LoginName before the UserInfoList data on SPWeb will synchronize with profile.

Our users don't want to waiting to sync-job will fill all of the user data on site (all of our users already have user profiles).

- It's impossible by policies to use IHttpModule to do that on-demand
- It's impossible to handle User creation on web site (EventHandlers don't work with UserInfoList)
- It's impossible to use audit (because it's also need a time to handle)

What may you suggest in this scenario to sync user data on the spweb from profile on the first-time login?

Comment: Not sure what you are saying here. Is the problem that user profile synchronization takes too long and you want profile data in the meantime?

Answer (score -2):

Try this [Having fun with the SharePoint Welcome.ascx control](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Having-fun-with-the-SharePoint-Welcomeascx-control.aspx)